# how to move in a matrix to reach a goal using the least number of moves

Tags: c, concurrency, path, minimum

I have recently started programming in c, I would have a problem to solve, in practice I am developing a small game where in a first phase, I randomly place a number of pawns on a matrix, and in a second time I place the flags to conquer
Each pawn has a target index, which corresponds to a placed flag, and has a number of moves to reach it
How can I find an optimal path that from the starting index leads me to a goal with a number of moves <= number of moves for each piece?

Comment: Suggestion: make a [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics))

Comment: Are two pawns allowed to simultaneously occupy one place?

Comment: @SimonCrane no two pawns can occupy different squares

Answer (score 1):

> How can I find an optimal path that from the starting index leads me to a goal with a number of moves <= number of moves for each piece?

If I understand correctly you are looking for pathfinding algorithm(s) for determine the optimal path.

You can use **BFS (Breadth First Search)** or **DFS (Depth-First Search)** but there's a lot more algorithms, find info [here](https://medium.com/omarelgabrys-blog/path-finding-algorithms-f65a8902eb40) and if you want to test in you browser I recommend you this [github page](http://qiao.github.io/PathFinding.js/visual/)

In term of code you will find implementations of these algorithms on internet, and lots of information directly on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

When there is a matrix involved, you usually can use nested for loops to iterate throughout all the points of the matrix. Since every pawn has its own target flag, you should have the position in the matrix for each pawn and flag. If, for example, its a 6 by 6 matrix, your pawn is at position 5,0 and the target flag is at position 0,0 you have to decrement the y for your pawn. However if the number of moves for this pawn is 3 its somehow imposible to reach the flag. I guess that's a start and then you build up from there?